# Is Visual Studio 2010 RC ever going to expire?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is Visual Studio 2010 RC ever going to expire? Sorry if this isn't the correct place to ask but it doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[June 30, 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/jasonz/archive/2010/02/10/visual-studio-2010-net-framework-4-rc-ready-for-general-download.aspx)

Comment: Damn , no free stuff as usual

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know all non-RTM releases of Visual Studio are time bombed in some manner.  I don't expect the 2010 RC to be any different.

I believe the expiration date is 6/30/2010.

Comment: Do you know if the upgrade path from RC to RTM release is easy or is it a hellish uninstall/reinstall process?

Answer (score 2):

If you have VS 2010 RC installed, go to Help | About Visual Studio, it says in the top right corner how many days of use you have remaining. And today 30/03/2010 it says 91 days.

Comment: They'll probably open source it ;->

Comment: It seems quite expensive for home use - VS2008 is £700 approximately!